# Opening a new component in child window in IE11 does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-11

I followed example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbapx4?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

resulting with code that executes after (click) event:

```
     const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ExampleComponent);
     let componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector);
     this.OpenWindow = window.open('','childwindow', 'width=400, height=400, left=150, top=200');
     this.OpenWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "";
     this.OpenWindow.document.body.appendChild(componentRef.location.nativeElement);
```

which works perfectly fine in Chrome and FF, but it does not work in IE, it opens child window without content, it's just empty and in the "main console" it results with HierarchyRequestError. How can I make it working in IE?

I can't use solutions that use routing, that's why I keep trying to modify above code.
I've tried also the solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-window with CdkPortal which appears to be impossible to run in IE.

Comment: It seems due to IE's limitation of allowing for DOM nodes to be moved from one window to another. You could consider to use javascript method to append elements to child window. For more detailed information, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260599/appending-children-into-a-popup-window-javascript).